# Transactions is not rolled back with MySQL/InnoDB

Tags: mysql, transactions, innodb

Why the following transaction is not rolled back when using InnoDB engine?

```
create table test ( i integer ) Engine = InnoDB;
begin;
insert into test(i) values(10);
insert into test(i) values(20);
rollback;
select count(*) from test;
```

returns 2 instead of 0!

What do I miss? Why does this happen? What should be done to make it behave correctly?

**Edit:**

- Same does not work if I use `start transaction` instead of `begin`
- I've tried with both 5.0.51 AND 5.1.49 on Debian Lenny x86_64.

**Answer:**

I've reinstalled from the scratch the DB including full removal of previous installations (purge) - and reinstalled from the beginning.

Now it works.

I would be very glad if somebody can explain me what went wrong!

Comment: where's your `START TRANSACTION`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's anything wrong with your code. Here's exactly that code on MySQL Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.44 on Mac, showing the result you're expecting:

```
mysql> create table test (i integer) Engine = InnoDB;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.10 sec)

mysql> begin;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into test(i) values(10);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> insert into test(i) values(20);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> rollback;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select count(*) from test;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|        0 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql>
```

What version of MySQL are you using? What platform? How are you entering those commands? Is is possible you're entering each individual command in a new connection, for example? That might explain the behaviour.

Comment: Wired! `select version()` gives `5.0.51a-24+lenny1-log` on Debian Linux x86\_64 and I typed then exactly as you did (from running mysql from command line using same connection)

Comment: I've installed version `5.1.49` still same result.

Comment: Ok - I removed alll the installation of mysql including databases and configuration and installed new... Now this works.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You're missing a `START TRANSACTION` or `BEGIN` statement for your `ROLLBACK` to have any context.</strike>

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html

I see your MySQL installation was broken. Glad you fixed it!

Comment: I've tried all `start transaction`, `begin`, `START TRANSACTION WITH CONSISTENT SNAPSHOT` the result the same. I've read this link but still can't figure out what to do. Can you please give a sample?